# Reactstrap Media object how to change the image size

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I am using the Reactstrap Media object to add in image into the website but having difficulties changing the image size. May I ask how I can change the image size in the Media object?

```
<Media object src={themes.image} alt={themes.name} />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change image size like below.

```
const imgStyle = {
  maxHeight: 128,
  maxWidth: 128
}

<Media object src={themes.image} style={imgStyle} alt={themes.name} />
```

Note: React by default adds px to the numbers if we don't specify explicitly. Here 128 is 128px

Answer (score 1):

The list of props for Media has `className` so you can give a class in your css file like,

```
.my_image{
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
}
```

and use the Media as,

```
<Media object src={themes.image} alt={themes.name} className='my_image' />
```